# How to search column elements and corresponding mappings in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, search, mapping

I have a dataframe **df1** such as the following that has a list of tags.

```
                       tags
            0            label
            0         document
            0             text
            0            paper
            0           poster
                     ...    
            21600         wood
            21600      hot tub
            21600          tub
            21600      terrace
            21600      blossom
```

There's another dataframe **df2** that has mappings to the tags present in df mapped to a column name 'name'.

```
                name        iab
        0   abies       Nature and Wildlife 
        1   absinthe    Food & Drink    
        2   abyssinian  Pets    
        3   accessories Style & Fashion 
        4   accessory   Style & Fashion 
          ...   ... ... ... ...

        1595 rows × 4 columns
```

Essentially, the idea is to search the column 'name' in df2 that correspond to the tags in df1 to find corresponding 'iab' mappings and output a CSV that has two columns - tags and it's corresponding 'iab' mappings.

The Output would look something like this :

```
                        tags      iab
            0            label    <corresponding iab mapping 
                                   to 'name' found in df2>
            0         document
            0             text
            0            paper
            0           poster
                     ...    
            21600         wood
            21600      hot tub
            21600          tub
            21600      terrace
            21600      blossom
```

I need help in achieving this. Thank you in advance!

Note:

What I tried is

```
    df_iab[df_iab['name'].isin(df['image_CONTAINS_OBJECT'])]
```

But that would only cut down df2 to 'iab' that match 'tags' but not really perform a search and map found values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to use `.map` to transfer `iab` details from `df2` to `df1`.

```
df1['iab']=df1.tags.map(dict(zip(df2.name,df2.iab)))
```

**How it works**

```
#come up with a dictionary of name and `iab` in `df2`.

d=dict(zip(df2.name,df2.iab))

# Map the dict to df1 using the tag column

df1.tags.map(d)
```

Comment: Thank you!! It worked out great!

Answer (score 1):

Merge:

```
new_df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='tags', right_on='name')
```